# Can't paint on certain parts on mesh while at certain angles

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, texture-painting, .fbx

So, I'm having this weird problem when trying to paint my mesh.

I had made my mesh in blender, and went and started painting, it was all fine and good, no problems at all. I saved, exited blender and headed off for the night.

Next day I found out that due to placing the saved blender file in the wrong folder, it got accidentally deleted, and all I was left with was a fbx file I had exported after I finished the modeling, but before I started painting it.

I got the Uv mapping set up and such, and started painting, but I noticed that it wouldn't paint on at all / correctly at certain angles, creating these ugly annoying jagged lines I suppose you could call them.

Here is me doing a direct side white paint on with no moving of the camera.
[image: Directly painting on the side of the anvil but it won't paint the sides of it]

I have tried increasing and decreasing the bleed and toggling backface culling to no avail.

Is there a way to fix this issue? or do I have to remodel my anvil from scratch to fix it?